# Fill attribute in svg can't be overwrite in mat-icon

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material

I want to use mat-icon for `svg` images but I can't change `fill` color. The problem is `svg` has an attribute `fill` which is set to `#000000` and can't be overridden in any possible way.

In component:

```ts
this._iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('close', this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('/assets/images/ic_clear_black_24px.svg'));
```

In HTML template:

```html
<span class="auth--icon">
    <mat-icon svgIcon="close"></mat-icon>
</span>
```

CSS:

```css
svg {
    color: red !important;
    fill: currentColor !important;
}
```

[image: Chrome DevTools of element tab and styles tab]

If I put this code in `element.style` this can be overridden.

[image: Chrome DevTools of element tab and styles tab]

For example on [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/examples) `svg[Attributes Style]` does not have `fill` attribute and everything works.

[image: Styles tab in Chrome DevTools]

---

UPDATE 2018-04-12

I finally found the cause of the issue. In my `reset.css` file, I had defined something like this:

```
svg {
  /*
  For IE9. Without, occasionally draws shapes
  outside the boundaries of <svg> rectangle.
  */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and I can't override style for `svg` element in my others `.scss` files.

Comment: Please update your question to include your actual html for the .svg icon.

Comment: Now there is some more information what is in HTML and angular component.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the *angular material* example, your CSS rule is applied because your `<path>` element indeed has no other `fill` rule set than the one it inherits from `.mat-icon` one (which sets it to `currentColor`).

But when there is a `fill` attribute set on the `<path>` element, then this rule takes precedence over the inherited one.

Luckily, it's still a poor rule, so you can override it quite easily:

```css
.mat-icon {
  fill: red;
}
.mat-icon rect { /* change 'rect' to whatever tag you target */
  fill: green;
}
/* you can even set it to 'inherit' and it will work */
.mat-icon rect:hover {
  fill: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="mat-icon">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Now, you may face something you didn't expected which is that paths which should have `fill="none"` attribute now are filled.
To overcome this, you'd have to make your selector a bit more complex:

```css
.mat-icon {
  fill: red;
}
/* beware it doesn't handle all possibilities of transparency, there are too many... */
.mat-icon path:not([fill='none']):not([fill="transparent"]){
  fill: inherit;
}

.bad-icon {
  fill: red;
}
.bad-icon path {
  fill: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="mat-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
    <path fill="orange" d="M1 21h4V9H1v12zm22-11c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-6.31l.95-4.57.03-.32c0-.41-.17-.79-.44-1.06L14.17 1 7.59 7.59C7.22 7.95 7 8.45 7 9v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h9c.83 0 1.54-.5 1.84-1.22l3.02-7.05c.09-.23.14-.47.14-.73v-1.91l-.01-.01L23 10z"></path>
</svg>
</div>

<div class="bad-icon">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
    <path fill="orange" d="M1 21h4V9H1v12zm22-11c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-6.31l.95-4.57.03-.32c0-.41-.17-.79-.44-1.06L14.17 1 7.59 7.59C7.22 7.95 7 8.45 7 9v10c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h9c.83 0 1.54-.5 1.84-1.22l3.02-7.05c.09-.23.14-.47.14-.73v-1.91l-.01-.01L23 10z"></path>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is not `fill` attribute in `<path>` but in `<svg>` like this `<svg fill="#000000" `. I can't override this in any way. In angualr material example ther is not `fill` attribute in `<svg>` I don't know why.

Comment: @Verri the same applies. If you set a CSS rule with higher importance, your CSS rule will win. With the current `.mat-icon { fill: currentColor }`, inherited value from `<svg fill>` will win, because the inheritance chain is broken. So if you wish you can just set your rule to be `.mat-icon svg { fill: inherit }`, this way you wouldn't even have issues with paths that should be `fill=none`. https://jsfiddle.net/yr6vda4p/

Comment: yes, this is a normal behavior which should work. Problem was `svg` element in my `reset.css` file. I can't override this I dont know why. Very annyoing. 
Thanks for help anyway!